# .net Core how to use User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I step by step with MSDB to creating an authentication cookie

step 1. setting start.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
               CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            );
            services.AddDbContext<CoreContext>(options =>
                  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB")));

            services.AddMvc();
}
```

step 2. add claims to ClaimsIdentity()

```
 var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone, ""),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "")
                };
 var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity("Custom");
 userIdentity.AddClaims(claims);
 ClaimsPrincipal userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
 HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, userPrincipal);
```

last step on other action to get `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` state

but state always false how to fix problem?

[This is my source code](https://github.com/hauserJr/CoreTemp/tree/master/CoreTemp_Alpha)

Comment: Is your last step after the step 2 or is in other request?

Comment: `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is part of the authentication system, which is separate from the identity system. You need something that actually authenticates the user (for example, an Open ID Connect server such as IdentityServer4) -- something that handles the sign-in / sign-out process. If you're intending to use ASP.NET Core Identity, you're missing a _lot_ of setup code and should review the docs.

Comment: SignIn does not set User for the current request, it won't be set until the next request.

Comment: @ThiagoSilva  in other request

Comment: You also need UseAuthentication in Configure.

Comment: @Tratcher Yes.I have. in configure add app.UseAuthentication()

Comment: I add my source code in question

Comment: app.UseAuthentication(); must be before UseMvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("user", ""),
                    new Claim("role", "Member")
                };

            HttpContext.SignInAsync(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, SysBase.cookieName, "user", "role")));
```

Comment: What is Sysbase?